# Can AppleScript automatically press a key for me in an application?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator

I'm trying to devices an AppleScript that will automatically press the right arrow key for 1 second, then the left arrow key for 1 second and repeat this in an endless loop until I interrupt it.

Here is what I've come up with so far, but it's not quite working:

```
tell application "VisualBoyAdvance"
    repeat 100 times
        tell application "VisualBoyAdvance" to keystroke "124"
        delay 1
    end repeat     
end tell
```

Comment: Can you add a code sample of what you've tried so far? You will learn more from somebody giving feedback to your script than just from copying from somebody.

Comment: Interesting request. What do you need it for ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I guess he needs it to auto-hatch his pokemon egg...! I stumbled upon this question in the quest to do the same...

Answer (score 3):

You could repeat key code commands until the frontmost application changes:

```
delay 1
activate application "TextEdit"
tell application "System Events"
    repeat while (path to frontmost application) is (path to application "TextEdit")
        repeat 3 times
            key code 123
            delay 0.3
        end repeat
        repeat 3 times
            key code 124
            delay 0.3
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Shorter delays (including 0.2 seconds) made it difficult to stop the script. I had to hold ⌥⇧⌘⎋ to force quit TextEdit.

This moved left only once:

```
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    key down (character id 28)
    delay 5
    key up (character id 28)
end tell
```

- left: 123 / 28
- right: 124 / 29
- down: 125 / 31
- up: 126 / 30

Answer (score 1):

I just did some tests : AppleScript is not well suited for what you ask since it is Single Threaded. Therefore exiting the loop in such situation does not seem possible.

Here is a code that do what you want but without exiting the loop.

```
tell application "VisualBoyAdvance" to activate
repeat while true
    set mydate to current date
    repeat while ((current date) - mydate < 1)
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke (key code 124) -- right
    end repeat
    repeat while ((current date) - mydate < 1)
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke (key code 123) -- left
    end repeat
end repeat
```

If you run it it will freeze the computer by sending to much events.